# How to add something specific for 1 item in for-loop jQuery...?

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop

I created something like fallowing code:

```
<body>
    <table id="tab">
        <tr>1</tr>
        <tr>2</tr>
        <tr>3</tr>
        <tr>4</tr>
    </table>
    <button class="add-row">Add Row</button>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.add-row').click(function(){
                var lttr = $('#tab tr:last-child');
                var currenttr =  1;
                for (currenttr; currenttr <= 10; currenttr++ ) {
                    lttr.after('<tr></tr>');
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

this code add 10 row when u click on button.
but my problem is here: 
**I want to add my data attribute between items, (for example 4th and 5th) in for loop!**

i mean like this form:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr date-my-attr="value"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr> 
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

how can i do this...?

Comment: **If** you can keep your head when all about you \ Are losing theirs and blaming it on you, \ **If** you can trust yourself when all men doubt you, \ But make allowance for their doubting too; [**If** —
BY RUDYARD KIPLING](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/175772)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('.add-row').click(function(){
                var lttr = $('#tab tr:last-child');
                var currenttr =  1;
                for (currenttr; currenttr <= 10; currenttr++ ) {
                   if(currenttr==4 || currenttr==5 )
                   {
                    lttr.after('<tr date-my-attr="value" ></tr>');
                  } else{
                       lttr.after('<tr ></tr>');                   
                     }               
           }
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add the attribute to the 4th table row:

```
for (currenttr; currenttr <= 10; currenttr++ ) {
    if (currenttr == 4) {
        lttr.after('<tr date-my-attr="value"></tr>');
    }
    else {
        lttr.after('<tr></tr>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.add-row').click(function(){
                var currenttr =  1;
                var tr = ''
                for (currenttr; currenttr <= 10; currenttr++ ) {
                    if(currenttr == 4 || currenttr == 5){
                        tr += '<tr date-my-attr="value"></tr>';
                    }else{
                        tr += '<tr></tr>';
                    }
                }
                $('#tab').append(tr);
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should net you the desired results:

```
$(".add-row").click(addTenRows);

function addTenRows() {
    var rows = $("<div>");

    while ($(rows).children().length <= 10)
        $(rows).append($("<tr/>"));

    $("tr:eq(3)", rows).attr({"date-my-attr": "value"});

    $("#tab").append($(rows).children());
}
```